# Joomla custom query string login redirect

Tags: redirect, authentication, query-string, joomla3.4

I am trying to find a way of creating a link to take a user to the `/component/users/?view=login` page, and then when they have logged in redirect them to a page that is different from the 'Login Redirection Page' setting in the module.
I was wondering if this is possible using a query string like

```
<a href="/component/users/?view=login&redirect=RedirectPage"></a>
```

where I could use a different value for redirect for many different links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, *dude*. Could be slightly outdatted dependent on what version of Joomla your running; but should be similar logic.

**Step**:**1**
Open the file: home `directory/components/com_users/controllers/user.php`

**Step**:**2**
Search the below code near line:61

```
// Perform the log in.
  if (true === $app->login($credentials, $options)) {
   // Success
   $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', array());
   $app->redirect(JRoute::_($app->getUserState('users.login.form.return'), false));
  } else {
   // Login failed !
   $data['remember'] = (int)$options['remember'];
   $app->setUserState('users.login.form.data', $data);
   $app->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login', false));
  }
```

**Step**:**3**

After login set a Custom redirect

```
$app->redirect('index.php?option=com_chronocontact&chronoformname=Contact&Itemid=5&lang=en');
```

Replace the below line with above code

```
$app->redirect(JRoute::_($app->getUserState('users.login.form.return'), false));
```

---

▶ Also, I think there is [decent Joomla extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/redirect-on-login) out there for this kinda stuff.

Comment: It is nice to finally have an answer. I will try this and see if it works ;)